# Deep commentaries on the 2 stories of Rabbi Akiva laughing

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, maseches-makos, suffering

The Talmud at the end of the tractate [Makkos (24a-b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.24a.33?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) relates 2 stories about Rabbi Akiva laughing in the face of suffering. I was able to find nice commentaries explaining the simple ideas behind the stories (*Maharsha*, *haRif* and *Ein Yaakov*), and *Aruch LaNer* who brings a fantastic allegorical explanation.

I am looking for more sources with deeper commentaries on the text, either allegorical (*drush*) or kabbalistic in nature. I looked in the *Chida* but he writes in his [*sefer Marit haAyin*](https://www.sefaria.org/Marit_HaAyin_on_Makkot.24a.1?lang=bi) on the Talmud that he extensively wrote on these stories elsewhere and I don't know where. Others where I would customarily look are either very brief without in-depth coverage (*Benayahu*/*Ben Yehoyada*) or silent (*Chasam Sofer*).

Could you please give me some references? A very related theme would also be tying this to the beginning or the contents of the tractate, in the style of *Aruch LaNer*, for example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Distantly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63758/shouldnt-we-laugh-as-rabbi-akiva

Comment: The Maharal in his Netzach Yisroel has a chapter which starts off addressing this story. I forget where. Chapter 20 or 30 something.